# JavaFX: how to make Nodes interactable in a transparent scene?

Tags: javafx

I'm writing a program where I want to be able to drag (and do other interactions) a node around the Stage, but the Stage and scene are transparent so you can see your desktop and other applications behind it. This is what I have in Main to make the background transparent:

```
public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("scene.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0); -fx-border-color: black;");
    scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    stage.setTitle("JavaFX and Gradle");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
    root.setVisible(true);

    scene.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            System.out.println("pressed");
        }
    });

    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

I can click through the transparent parts to applications behind, which is what I want. However, I also can't interact with solid nodes in my scene; they are clicked through as well, which is not what I want. This appears only to be a problem when `-fx-background-color` has an alpha of zero.

For example's sake, say that node is a Button. I want are to be able to drag my it around the stage; I am able to drag it once, but then it becomes uninteractable again. Just clicking on the Button doesn't affect anything however. This is the scene fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>

<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.172-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="eldai.FXMLController">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="button" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

and controller:

```
public class FXMLController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private Button button;

private double xOffset = 0;
private double yOffset = 0;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    button.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler <MouseEvent>() {
        public void handle(MouseEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("button pressed");
            xOffset = e.getX();
            yOffset = e.getY();
            e.setDragDetect(true);
        }
    });

    button.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler <MouseEvent>() {
        public void handle(MouseEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("Button released.");
            e.setDragDetect(false);

        }
    });

    button.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                button.setLayoutX(e.getSceneX() - xOffset);
                button.setLayoutY(e.getSceneY() - yOffset);
        }
    });
}

}
```

And the scene's controller pretty much does nothing. I tried setting MouseTransparent to false at various points, setPickOnBounds, etc. but none of it seems to work. I also why clicking the node is fine but as soon as i drag it, the interactability is lost. It's very important for my program for the scene background to stay transparent; am I missing something here?

P.S. I was originally trying to do this with custom FXML and all of this is still true, except i must wrap it in a Group if I want to be able to interact with it even just once. I'm new to JavaFX; can someone explain why that is as well?

Comment: Can you create a complete reproducible example of this (a [mre]: e.g. just one `Shape` that you drag around a transparent scene, minimal code so no FXML and no external CSS if possible)? It would be easier (for both us and you) to figure out a solution from that.

Comment: I updated my question; hopefully it's a little more clear now.

Comment: you can use in your start method  stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

Comment: stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true) keeps it visible, but I still can't interact with the button.

Comment: Your example works just fine for me.

Comment: I'm using JavaFX 14 on Windows, and for me after dragging it's like the whole stage clicks through. I think on iOS the dragging problem isn't there, but you can't click through the transparent parts.